# I've defined a path in d3.js, it draws correctly, but .getTotalLength() is undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

The following code generates a path from data.

```
var path = gameBoard.append('path')
   .attr("id", "snake" + snakeIndex)
   .attr("d", interpolator(data))
   .attr('stroke-width', snakeStroke)
   .attr('fill', 'none')
   .attr('stroke', config.snakeColor);
```

The curvy path defined by the data draws correctly.

Fails here getTotalLength() is not defined:

```
var totalLength = path.getTotalLength();
```

Additionally getPointAlongLength() is not defined either:

```
var point = path.getPointAtLength(position);
```

Answer (score 12):

Instead of:

```
var totalLength = path.getTotalLength();
```

It has to be:

```
var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
```

`getTotalLength()` works on the node, but `path` is a D3 selection, not the DOM element itself. So, you have to use `path.node()`.

Answer (score 3):

yes, I discovered I had to use path.node() to get the right object. The d3.js documentation is extremely hard to read, with few examples.